# Tokensale whitelist UI

Tags: solidity, web3js, ico, crowdsale

I am trying to design UI for a tokensale smart contract where all participants must be whitelisted before purchasing tokens.

The participants submit their address via the UI form, but only the contract owner can add addresses to whitelist.

Would the way to do this be to create an admin section that requires the admin use the owner's account in metamask and manually view and approve a list of submitted addresses?

Or is there another recommended way to implement a whitelisted tokensale?

Answer (score 2):

You can authenticate the user with OAuth (or whatever) and link that identifier to their Ethereum address by having them send a signed message to your server.

The actual whitelisting is usually done through a third party/back office process.

In the contract, you would have a privileged account that approves the addresses after the WL process is passed successfully. It's not something the user should be able to do for themselves.

This process will confirm that the `ComplianceOfficer` attests that the requirements for whitelisting have been fulfilled and the address is authorized to partcipate. Bearing in mind that the `ComplianceOfficer` may be a server following an automated or semi-automated process.

The contract will never know that "Alice" is "Alice" but it will know that the `ComplianceOfficer` attests that she (and her Ethereum address) have been approved. It's probably advisable to keep orderly off-chain records.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I see. The token sale contract has "function addToWhitelist(address _buyer) public onlyOwner" function. Where would this usually be called? Is it common for the contract owner to just interact with the contract using remix or MEW and add the addresses manually?

Comment: A trusted employee or a trusted machine that has the signing key and enough ether to pay for gas.

Comment: Is there a good way of sending the whitelist transaction from the owner's address using the private key and not using metamask etc as provider? How could I go about making this an automated compliance process?

Comment: Yes. A signing process will do. Metamask is just a browser way to do it. Use can use nodejs with the Web3 JS API, and use either a `geth` full node or BaaS like Infura. The "server" would sign with the owner's private key.

Comment: Thanks, we are using web3.js and infura. We could create an automated process which sends a signed transaction from owner, but wouldn't that potentially expose the hard coded private key?

Comment: You will probably have a mnemonic in a `env` and you will want to protect that from prying eyes.